# Execute .First() from .Rprofile on first login of the day only

Tags: r, automation, rstudio

I know that one can schedule scripts and processes with the `cron` scheduler to automate R processes at specific timepoints from R itself. I also know that you can place function(s) in your `.Rprofile` to have them execute every time R is started.

I figured out how to run a function within `.First()` only on Mondays but would like it to only run the first time a user opens `RStudio` on that Monday.

This is what I've got so far in my `.Rprofile`:

```
.First <- function(){
        today <- weekdays(as.Date(Sys.Date()))
if (today == "Monday"){
       print("Today is "Monday")
} else {
       print("Today is not Monday")
        }
}
```

What I would like to add to this code is a way to check the log and only display the message the first time a user logs in for the day, not every time they open/close projects, restart R, *etc.*.

Comment: Are you willing to write a file somewhere to store the date of last login?

Comment: Yes this seems reasonable. As long as the file doesn't swell in-size. It doesn't need to keep the first ever log-in (and every subsequent one), it could be reset once a week for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code tests for a file called LogFile.txt. Ypu may want to name it something else or hide it in some obscure directory. If the file exists, the code reads the first line of the file. It then stores today's date in the first line of the file to handle later logins. If the first line of the file contained today's date, the function just returns so that the test for Monday is not run. If either the file did not exist or it did not contain today's date, the Monday test is run.

```
.First <- function(){
    today <- as.Date(Sys.Date())
    LastLog <- ""
    if(file.exists("LogFile.txt")) {
       LogFile <- file("LogFile.txt", open="r")
       LastLog <- readLines(LogFile, 1L)
       close(LogFile)
    }
    LogFile <- file("LogFile.txt", open="w")
    writeLines(as.character(today), LogFile) 
    close(LogFile)

    if(LastLog == as.character(today)) {
       # Already logged on today, just exit
       return()
    }

    ## If you get here, Need to run the first login code
    DOW <- weekdays(today)
    if (DOW == "Monday") { 
       print("Today is Monday") 
    } else {
       print("Today is not Monday")
    }
}
```